# Obtener hora actual con php

Tags: php, html, html5

Este código me devuelve la hora actual, pero la necesito con un minuto atrás.

```
  <input type="text" value="<?php echo date("h:i:s A");?>">
```

¿Se puede hacer que si la hora actual son 14:00; el input me muestre las 13:59?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El segundo argumento *(opcional)* de la función `date()` es un *timestamp*. Así que puedes colocar como primer argumento el formato y como segundo argumento `strtotime("-1 minute")`:

```
  <input type="text" value="<?php echo date("h:i:s A", strtotime("- 1 minute"));?>">
```

Comment: ME SIRVIO PARA OBTENER LA HORA PERO NO ES LA HORA DE MI REGION COMO CONFIGURO ESO

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php) para ello

```
$nuevafecha = strtotime ( '-1 minute' , strtotime ( date("h:i:s A")) ) ;

<input type="text" value="<?php echo $nuevafecha ;?>">
```

Calculado en el input directamente

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo strtotime ( '-1 minute' , strtotime ( date("h:i:s A")) );?>">
```

Comment: Revisa el resultado que da tu función